# Setter for AutocompleteBox Doesn't Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I need to the property in the class to update as selecteditems are changed. But when I set a breakpoint for the setter, it's  never actually fired. May I ask how do I get around this?

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox ....
                            SelectedItems"{Binding Occurence.Appointment.SelectedAttendees, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            .../>
```

CustomAppointment.cs

```
public BindableCollection<AttendeeSearchDTO> SelectedAttendees
{
    get
    {
        return selectedAttendees;
    }
    set
    {            
        if (selectedAttendees != value)
        {
            selectedAttendees = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedAttendees);
        }
    }
}
```

I can set a break point for other components such as below, and it fires completely fine.

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding Occurrence.Appointment.Body, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: You have a spelling mistake for RadAutoCompleteBox.

Comment: Can you show your ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ObservableCollection instead of BindableCollection

```
public ObservableCollection <AttendeeSearchDTO> SelectedAttendees
{
    get
    {
        return selectedAttendees;
    }
    set
    {            
        if (selectedAttendees != value)
        {
            selectedAttendees = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedAttendees);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, bindablecollection is an extension of ObservableCollection. But I've tried your suggestions, and same thing.

Comment: Update your xaml referring to this:<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding Countries, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"
                            DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>

Comment: why would I update my xaml to point to a static resource. That doesn't answer the question. It has to be the fact that AutocompleteBox stores the collection in a dictionary.